# Wrong checksum on stacked writer & zlib.writer

Tags: go, sha1, zlib

I have two object writers, first one encapsulates `io.Writer` and along writes it also coputes SHA1 checksum of content, and second encapsulates first and writes zlib compressed data.

My unit test case with some test data passes for first writer, but fails with second.

Where and what I'm doing wrong?

code snippet:

```
import (
    "compress/zlib"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "hash"
    "io"
)

type ObjectWriter interface {
    io.Writer
    Commit() ([]byte, error)
}

type oWriter struct {
    writer io.Writer
    sum    hash.Hash
}

func (ow *oWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    ow.sum.Write(b)  // Hash writer never returs error -> hash.Hash docs
    return ow.writer.Write(b)
}

func (ow *oWriter) Commit() ([]byte, error) {
    return ow.sum.Sum(nil), nil
}

func NewWriter(w io.Writer) ObjectWriter {
    return &oWriter{w, sha1.New()}
}

type compressedWriter struct {
    oWriter ObjectWriter
    zWriter io.WriteCloser
}

func (ow *compressedWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return ow.zWriter.Write(b)
}

func (ow *compressedWriter) Commit() ([]byte, error) {
    if err := ow.zWriter.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return ow.oWriter.Commit()
}

func NewCompressedWriter(w io.Writer) ObjectWriter {
    ow := NewWriter(w)
    zw := zlib.NewWriter(ow)

    return &compressedWriter{ow, zw}
}
```

passing test case:

```
func TestObjectWriter(t *testing.T) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    ow := NewWriter(&buf)
    ow.Write([]byte("test content"))
    sum, err := ow.Commit()

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Commit error: %s", err)
    }

    expected := "1eebdf4fdc9fc7bf283031b93f9aef3338de9052"
    given := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sum)

    if  expected != given {
        t.Errorf("Invalid SHA1 sum: <%s> != <%s>", expected, given)
    }
}
```

failing test case:

```
func TestCompressedObjectWriter(t *testing.T) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    ow := NewCompressedWriter(&buf)
    ow.Write([]byte("test content"))
    sum, err := ow.Commit()

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Commit error: %s", err)
    }

    expected := "7efbe4015afd95478282c3774f47b4195031d27e"
    given := fmt.Sprintf("%x", sum)

    if  expected != given {
        t.Errorf("Invalid SHA1 sum: <%s> != <%s>", expected, given)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was your test output?

How did you calculate your expected values?

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/zlib"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "fmt"
)

func ObjectHash(s string) (string, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    _, err := buf.Write([]byte(s))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    hash := sha1.New()
    hash.Write(buf.Bytes())
    sum := fmt.Sprintf("%x", hash.Sum(nil))
    return sum, nil
}

func CompressedHash(s string) (string, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    zw := zlib.NewWriter(&buf)
    _, err := zw.Write([]byte(s))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    zw.Close()
    hash := sha1.New()
    hash.Write(buf.Bytes())
    sum := fmt.Sprintf("%x", hash.Sum(nil))
    return sum, nil
}

func main() {
    s := "test content"
    sum, err := ObjectHash(s)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Object:    ", sum)
    }
    sum, err = CompressedHash(s)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Compressed:", sum)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Object:     1eebdf4fdc9fc7bf283031b93f9aef3338de9052
Compressed: 8138de8ff9d0cd30126f7e26191996dce781d652
```

If you compare apples and oranges, SHA1, by design, can tell the difference between different types of fruit.

```
Apples (Go):

00000000  78 9c 2a 49 2d 2e 51 48  ce cf 2b 49 cd 2b 01 04  |x.*I-.QH..+I.+..|
00000010  00 00 ff ff 1f 29 04 dc                           |.....)..|

$ sha1sum apples
8138de8ff9d0cd30126f7e26191996dce781d652  apples

Oranges (Python):

00000000  78 9c 2b 49 2d 2e 51 48  ce cf 2b 49 cd 2b 01 00  |x.+I-.QH..+I.+..|
00000010  1f 29 04 dc                                       |.)..|

$ sha1sum oranges
7efbe4015afd95478282c3774f47b4195031d27e  oranges
```

Comment: I've checked this in Python (and for double-check in PHP also): `hashlib.sha1(zlib.compress('test content')).hexdigest() == '7efbe4015afd95478282c3774f47b4195031d27e'`

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. See my revised answer.

Comment: <facepalm> sorry for bothering!